# Tomcat & CORS exception

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, cors, apt-get

After some issues I completely reinstalled tomcat7 with apt-get and I'm now with v7.0.52. When I try to start the server though I get the following exception:

> Feb 27, 2014 11:09:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext filterStart
>   SEVERE: Exception starting filter CORS
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
>       at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:529)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:511)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:139)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:258)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:105)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4809)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5485)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1073)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1857)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1146)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:701)
>   Feb 27, 2014 11:09:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
>   SEVERE: Error filterStart

What am I missing? Shouldn't it work out of the box when I install tomcat without changes and just run the server?

Thanks for helping clueless me!

Comment: This should be commented out by default in your $CATALINA_BASE/conf/web.xml. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/filter.html#Introduction - yours are enabled somehow - you can comment these out

Comment: I commented out the cors filter + mapping and restarted the server, still the same error. I've already tried with enabling and disabling it but had no luck

Comment: your installation might be corrupted/incomplete - this class is found in `apache-tomcat-7.0.52\lib\catalina.jar` - do you have it there?

Comment: It's there I'm afraid. CorsFilter$1.class, CorsFilter$CORSRequestType.class, CorsFilter.class.

Comment: What I did was purging apt-get tomcat7 and then using --reinstall to reinstall the stuff should I first deinstall it or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the project itself - sorry. Someone once included a custom cors filter library which was referenced in the xml but not included anymore.
One could have recognized that in the upper stacktrace the namespace was

> com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter 
>   instead of an apache / catalina one.

Thanks for the help though!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes this error occurs with me (TomCat 7.0 / Maven / Eclipse in Linux Mint) when I try to start the application with tomcat.

I solved it by doing:

1. Maven clean within Eclipse
2. clicking refresh on the project inside Eclipse (right button, refresh)
3. Maven install with Eclipse again